# jQuery want to override function on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I already have a jQuery `.on()` function in which click event is passed on a button.

I want to restrict user from clicking button more than 1 but i don't want to alter current function instead write new function

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
    alert('hi');
});

$('button').click(function(event) {
    var count = 0;
    count = count + 1;
    if (count > 1) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('dont call alert');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Click Me !</button>
```

Comment: You can use jQuery .one(): http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: I already have a .on() function written in another file and i dont have access to that file ... so want to override it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery `off()` method remove event handler of element. You can remove `click` event of button when it clicked. Using this work, button click event fired only once.

```js
$("button").click(function(event){
    alert();
    $(this).off("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like following.

```js
$('button').on('click', function () {
    alert('hi');
});


var isCliked = true;
$('button').click(function () {
    $('button').off('click');

    isCliked && $('button').click(function() {
        console.log('dont call alert');
        isCliked = false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
    Click Me !
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method:

```js
$('button').one('click', function() {
    alert('hi');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Click Me !</button>
```

Comment: I already have a .on() function written in another file and i dont have access to that file ... so want to override it